# How to insert or delete a particular line of a file using FileSystem object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am able to read , write and append a file using filesystem object in javascript , but unable to insert or delete a particular line from the file already exists using same filesystem object in javascript.

So I need help of the community, please help me in this regard

Comment: how are you accessing the file? is this for nodejs?

Comment: *Which* "filesystem object" are you using? This is not a native JavaScript API, so you always need to link/tag it.

Comment: I am using new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");